# Why `select ... for update` statement locks more rows then total number of rows?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I use mysql 5.6. And I run below queries.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `passport_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `passport_id` (`passport_id`),
  KEY `idx_user_age` (`age`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

insert into user values(1, 'A', 'A1', 1), (2, 'B', 'B1', 1), (3, 'C', 'C3', 1), 
(4, 'A', 'A4', 2), (5, 'B', 'B5', 2), (6, 'C', 'C6', 2);

set autocommit = 0;
select * from user where age = 1 for update;
```

I expect that above `select...for update` query locks 3 rows. Because the query returns 3 rows. But the `trx_rows_locked` data of `select * from information_schema.innodb_trx;`  query is 7. Even the total number of row is 6.

In addition, below query returns only one row. But `trx_rows_locked` is 2.

```
select * from user where age = 1 and passport_id = 'A1' for update;
```

Mysql document explain `trx_row_locked` like this `The approximate number or rows locked by this transaction.` . But I can't understand why `trx_row_locked` have approximate number.
And how can I get correct number of locked rows?

Comment: Maybe:  (1) two unique keys; (2) "gap locking"

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail

Comment: Could you show the complete result of `select ... from innodb_trx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trx_rows_locked` is indeed the approximate number of `record locks` for this transaction, note that the count is not the row records in table. Since `delete-marked` records may be removed, the record count will not be precise.

```
select * from user where age = 1 for update;
```

Use full table scan, we could see the execute plan via **explain**, and thus it locked all the table, 6 records, plus a supremum record (in fact is a gap lock), so **trx_rows_locked = 6 + 1 = 7**

```
select * from user where age = 1 and passport_id = 'A1' for update;
```

Use unique index `passport_id`, and thus InnoDB will acquire a record lock on `passport_id` index, and a record lock on PK, so **trx_rows_locked = 2**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have one more question. Why `select * from user where age = 1 for update` statement uses full table scan? `age` column has non-unique index. so I  suppose it should use ref type.

Comment: This is because there are 3 records with `age = 1` in table (50% in table), MySQL thinks that using full table scan is faster than the secondary index.

Comment: See [Avoiding Full Table Scans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-scan-avoidance.html) for more details